# Using op-amp at high or low end of Vcc range

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, ac

I'm looking to find an op-amp that can run off a +/-2.5V supply, sampling 60Hz AC voltage signals.

With all else being equal with operational amplifiers, is it better to use a component that has a maximum Vcc rating (ex: **5.5V** max, 2.2V min), or min Vcc (ex: **4.5V** min, 36V max) close to your supply voltage?

I'm asking because I'm torn between the [TLV4197QPWRQ1](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv4197-q1.pdf?&ts=1589387514824) and [OPA4325IPWR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2325.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1609190033752&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.be%252F) as both will work well for my application.

[Mouser link to TLV4197QPWRQ1](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/texas-instruments/tlv4197qpwrq1/?qs=vmHwEFxEFR%2Fb6qx7C801BA%3D%3D&countrycode=US&currencycode=USD)

[Mouser link to OPA4325IPWR](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/OPA4325IPWR/?qs=%2Fha2pyFadugCEqG2exCRYY7guzo1CwjiHmKeThLxGBBNpkt0h0d7nA%3D%3D)

Comment: Depends what you're doing. Generally speaking, ability to take some overvoltage is def. nice to have if you have larger voltages kicking around. The 4197's performance might degrade a bit when approaching the positive rail, and there is a point in the CM voltage about 1.5V below the positive rail where the input bias current changes polarity, I believe, which is it's only significant weakness IMO. (see Figure 2 in its datasheet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will both work off the total 5 V you have available, so without knowing more about your application, either will do.

If you want to find a 'best', or an 'only', then you'll have to trawl through the other parameters until you find one that completely disqualifies the part.

These parameters are very different (more than 2:1 ratio) between the two

- typical and maximum bias current
- slew rate
- output current
- noise when near the +ve rail

The killer may be that the TLV has crossover distortion around an input voltage 3 V below the top rail. However, it's only a few 10s of μV, so the precision of your application will determine whether that rules the part out, or is insignificant.